# How to start Oracle DB and how to connect to it?

Tags: oracle, oracle12c

I have downloaded latest Database App Development Virtual Machine with Oracle Linux 7 and Oracle Database 12c Release 1 Enterprise Edition (12.1.0.2 with In-Memory Option) and Oracle SQL Developer.

How do i start database or verify that it is running?
How do I connect to it?

Comment: there should be a read me file here: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/enterprise-edition/databaseappdev-vm-161299.html and another file on the desktop of the vm with instructions for starting the db.

Comment: read me file in vm does not cover that, there are passwords, links to tutorials resets, DB SID, but nothing about running database itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i just checked and the db is already running. Open an xterm window and type sqlplus system/oracle and you'll be logged into the db. It's all set to go. Firefox - Apex is working. SQLDeveloper is setup with a connection to System, password is "oracle".

And, if you go to Applications > System Tools > System Monitor and click on Processes and scroll down you'll see many "ora_" processes - these are the oracle server background processes running. If you connected to the database, one will represent your forground, connected process.

Please note. this is a lab environment meant for people to learn about developing apps on oracle. Consider [this one](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/community/developer-vm/vts-hol-2415742.html) for more "DBA" type learning and more info on startup/shut down.

Comment: It worked now. I have set previously VM memory to 1500 from 2048 could this prevent DB from working?

Comment: Per the readme  "At least 2GB RAM. Default VM is 1G RAM, for better performance increase." It depends what the database memory is set to. I doubt that would prevent it starting if the vm is set to 1GB to start. You can check the ram allocation of the DB by logging into sqlplus as system/oracle and issuing "SHOW PARAMETER TARGET" Either Memory_Target or SGA+ PGA will give you ram allocation to db: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28310/memory003.htm#ADMIN11200